# Consumo de Webservice HTTPS con ASP CLASSIC

Tags: asp

Estoy consumiendo un Webservice con ASP Classic y me funciona perfectamente pero cuando cambio la URL a HTTPS me genera un error, me imagino por el certificado, pero no se como solucionarlo, ya he intentado muchas formas que consigo en foros pero no he tenido exito, consulto si es algo de configuracion o de instalacion del certificado. o si es algo que puedo solucionar con codigo?

Agradezco su ayuda o comentarios.

Aqui el codigo:

```
Function PostWebservice( AsmxUrl  ,  SoapActionUrl,  xmlBody  )  
  Dim objDom 
   Dim objXmlHttp
   Dim strRet 
   Dim intPos1 
   Dim intPos2 

   ' Create objects to DOMDocument and XMLHTTP
   Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

   'Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   'Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
   Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
   'Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
   'Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   'Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

   objXmlHttp.setOption 2, 13056
   ' Load XML
   objDom.async = False
   objDom.loadXML xmlBody
   ' Open the webservice
   objXmlHttp.Open "POST", AsmxUrl, False
   ' Create headings
   objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
   objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


   objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SoapActionUrl
   ' Send XML command
   objXmlHttp.send objDom.xml
   ' Get all response text from webservice
   strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText
   ' Close object
   Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
   ' Extract result
   intPos1 = InStr(strRet, "Result>") + 7
   intPos2 = InStr(strRet, "<!--")
   If intPos1 > 7 And intPos2 > 0 Then
       strRet = Mid(strRet, intPos1, intPos2 - intPos1)
   End If
   ' Return result
   PostWebservice = strRet
End Function
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Puedes probar con `objXmlHttp.setOption(2, 0x3300)` para evitar los errores de servidor